# How to show serial number in RecyclerView in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm making a ranking activity using RecyclerView,

[image: Here is an Image of Ranking Activity].

I want to show serial number (1,2,3.....and so on) in front of each profile picture. How can I do it?

```
 // Rank View Holder
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Query query = playerDB.orderByChild("score");
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Rank, RankViewHolder>  firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Rank, RankViewHolder>(

            Rank.class,
            R.layout.player_single_rank_layout,
            RankViewHolder.class,
            query
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(RankViewHolder viewHolder, Rank model, int position) {

                viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
                viewHolder.setScore(model.getScore());
                viewHolder.setThumbImage(model.getThumbImage(), getApplicationContext());

        }
    };

    playerRankList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


}
```

Comment: share your efforts, code that you have tried

Comment: @GautamChibde, I'm new to coding and not sure how to move forward what I want. Though I have update question with how I'm populating RecyclerView, I hope it will be sufficient to show I'm trying to learn as I can't post more code in question because it showing error message " question is mostly code".

Comment: first of all, i dont know much about Recyclerview, but you have a `position` in your `pupulateViewHolder`. Can't you set that position into a textview or whatever?

Comment: @Ivan I think you have pointed me in the right direction. I will try it in few hours and will let you know if it works.

Comment: @Ivan Thank you very much. It worked

Comment: Great! Happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
 public static  class RankViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;
    TextView rankPosition;
    public RankViewHolder(View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       mView = itemView;

        rankPosition = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.rankPosition);

    }


 @Override
 protected void populateViewHolder(RankViewHolder viewHolder, Rank model,int position) {


                viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
                viewHolder.setRuns(model.getRuns());
                viewHolder.setThumbImage(model.getThumbImage(), getApplicationContext());
                // Getting positions here
                viewHolder.rankPosition.setText(String.valueOf(position));
        }
```

Thanks Ivan for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I tried to edit this answer because as per this answer `String.valueOf(position)` will show 0,1,2,3... and user has asked that how to get 1,2,3,4... That's why I changed position to position + 1 but some nonsense has rejected my changed without checking it properly.

Answer (score 0):

```java
viewHolder.rankPosition.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
```

to display 1,2,3,4,...